# Connecting to local SQL Server ASP.Net Core Entity Framework from Excel 2016

Tags: entity-framework, excel, adodb, vba

I am working with Visual Studio 2017 and have an MVC app that uses Entity Framework that creates a local SQL Server database for the Entity stuff.

What I am trying to do is to connect to that database from Excel.

I have the connection string form the database, but can't seem to get Excel to create an ADODB connection to it. I am getting a Run-time error '-2147217887 (80040e21): Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done. It is failing on the cn.Open below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection

strCon = "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=PropertyValContext-57e4e5c8-9272-493b-ab16-74faf5d4318f;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"

cn.Open strCon
```

Comment: Are you sure this is right?
     Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB

Comment: It is the connection string I get from SQL Server Object Explorer in Visual Studio 2017. The server does run on my local PC at the moment, so I suspect it is, but I am not really sure.

Comment: Visual Studio isn't VBA, and may accept more parameters.
https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/  has simpler versions. Start with one of them and work up?